# To manage PUSH from notification of other applications

Tags: android, push-notification, android-service, android-notifications

I'm creating an application for Android as a NotificationListenerService to try to intercept notifications. The intent is to intercept all notifications and pass only the subscriptions in the application.

Until then use or onNotificationPosted method (StatusBarNotification sbn) to read a notification, this works to a certain extent. I can read a notification and remove it from the Notification-Bar, but the PUSH event of all applications continues to notify (ring and vibrate).

I wonder if it is possible to manage this PUSH of notification of other applications, not only mine?

Example: The user configured my application to receive GMAIL notification, if I receive a WhatsApp notification, it must pass in my Listener and not allow that notification to be in the notification bar and not be notified (Push)

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if it is possible to manage this PUSH of notification of other applications, not only mine?

You cannot prevent apps from using the Internet or from using the vibration motor.

> if I receive a WhatsApp notification, it must pass in my Listener and not allow that notification to be in the notification bar and not be notified (Push)

If WhatsApp receives data from the Internet (e.g., GCM/FCM-style push messages), WhatsApp can do whatever it wants, including vibrate the device.

Comment: But can I block GCM / FCM notifications? In time execution.

Comment: @JulioMachado: No.